# Link quantity to product variations in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to link the product variation to the quantity on woocommerce in WordPress 4.9.8, and I installed [Quantities and Units for WooCommerce](https://co.wordpress.org/plugins/quantities-and-units-for-woocommerce/) plugin.

This plugin just let me set the minimum and maximum quantities but it's not attached to the product variations. In the image bellow you can see the quantity that doesn't change with the product variation:

[image: Actual state]

Is there any way to do that?

I was searching and I found that the people said that I can do that in php but I have a poor knowledge .

Any help on this please.

Comment: To link the quantity attribute of a product variation to woocommerce quantity, is something advanced and complicated, so a real development and then something **too broad** for stackOverFlow. As you don't have any knowledge, you should better hire a developer.

Comment: Hi loic, i know java scrip and python but i dont know so much about php, i was searching and i found that i have to modify the variation.php and quantiti.php on woocommerce the thing that i dont know is how to link those i called like a object or how can i do that? that a lot for the reply